# How to perform 'SELECT a or b < c FROM Table' on Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class DiscountCoupon(models.Model):
   is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   expiration_date = models.DateField()

   def is_available(self):
      if self.used or self.expiration_date <= date.today():
         return False
      return True
```

Instead of calling the `is_available` method iterating through a QuerySet, I want to do this operation into the QuerySet to perform better, like this:

```
SELECT (used OR (expiration_date < Now())) AS is_available FROM randomapp_discountcoupon;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Q objects [Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) with [**Case[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) expression as

```
from django.db.models import Q, Case, Value, When

discount_objects = DiscountCoupon.objects.annotate(
    is_available=Case(
        When(Q(is_used=True) | Q(expiration_date__lt=datetime.date.today()), then=Value(True)), 
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
     )
)
```

Comment: This work if I want to filter. But I want to get the result, True of False, from the DB.

Comment: @Alan then just use `DiscountCoupon.objects.filter(...).exists()`

Comment: Then you can use `Case` `When`. See I have updated my answer.